# WP7 Testing on phone device error but fine on emulator

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, odata

I get an error when debugging on my phone device but not on the emulator. It appears to error every time data is requested from the server (hosted using WCF/Odata using IIS Express). The code concerned is below (note that the problem occurs on ALL data access):

```
public void LoadData()
    {
        IsDataLoaded = false;

        string queryUri = string.Format("Jobs?$filter=ApplicantID eq {0}", 1);
        jobData.LoadAsync(new Uri(queryUri, UriKind.Relative));
        jobData.LoadCompleted += new EventHandler<LoadCompletedEventArgs>(jobData_LoadCompleted);
    }

    void jobData_LoadCompleted(object sender, LoadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            if (jobData.Continuation != null)
            {
                jobData.LoadNextPartialSetAsync();
            }
        }

        IsDataLoaded = true;
    }
```

When I use the emulator, everything goes OK, however when I use my WP7 device I get a great error: An error occurred while processing this request

Even better, the inner exception just says NotFound.

Even the stacktrace isn't that helpful:

```
 at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, DataServiceContext context, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.EndExecute[TElement](IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceCollection`1.<>c__DisplayClass6.<LoadAsync>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceCollection`1.<>c__DisplayClass11.<>c__DisplayClass13.<BeginLoadAsyncOperation>b__f()
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
 at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
 at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
 at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
 at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
 at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
 at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)
 at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
 at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
 at System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
 at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)
```

Has anyone had this and resolved it previously?

Comment: Smells  like the the query failed - "Not found". Have you confirmed that all data links are up? Maybe you can prove this by stubbing out the call. Also write a simple  a test program that calls the Server synchronously and gets some data to verify the link.

Comment: The query seems fine, when I use the built in emulator everything works out great. Would there be an issue with the server being localhost? Would the phone device not be able to connect to that but the emulator would?

Comment: localhost is the local machine no? Ask yourself this - is the WP7 device the same machine?

Comment: So, would I need to publish the service before testing on a device? I would have thought that the cable connecting would allow communication but if not then that's the reason.

Comment: I don't know the reason. I'm just going on what you've said. Personally I'd test ensure the comms was working.  If the reason is that the device cannot connect to your service then yes perhaps you need to ensure that the device can see service first. Localhost is just a nickname for ip address 127.0.0.1 which ensures that IP traffic goes to the local machine and not on the network. Why can't you use the full name of your server in your app?